# How to play animation using animator in unity once every time on some event?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I know that `animator.Play("anim")` will play the animation depending whether animation clip in loop , once ,default etc.I want to play an animation every time I call `animator.Play("anim")` or with any button press and it should play the animation once and should stop which it does if uncheck the Loop Time option in animation clip but , my problem is that if I again call the `animator.Play("anim")` the animation doesn't play; also I don't want to use any parameter to trigger an animation because that will be lot of work for just playing a simple animation.  Example:- for more explanation I have created an animation and attached the below script to the animated object and did following tweaks in  animation clip.

[image][image][image]

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("New Animation");
        print("Should Play");
    }
}
```

Animation play only once when I press space ("Jump") and doesn't play if I again press space. I don't know how to do this , maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I'm guessing the Animator gets stuck on your New Animation state. You only have arrows towards it, meaning it can only get there once, then it's stuck. I'm not entirely sure this is how to works, but try setting an arrow from the New State to something else so it can loop. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Yes you are right @Fredrik ,  The "New Animation" got stuck never come to its beginning state , but unity documentation say that if  wrap mode is set to once then , **When time reaches the end of the animation clip, the clip will automatically stop playing and time will be reset to beginning of the clip.**

Comment: Hmm, right. The clip might reset but the animator gets stuck at the state because it's a dead end? So when you try to play the state again it can't because there's no path to go there? (Again, I'm just speculating, I have never tried anything like this)

Comment: Did you get it working? What was the issue?

Comment: No I did't get any thing on that , so I did that animation thing marking the animation clip as Legacy (not using the Animator , instead I used Animation).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the code below to play the animation and reset the animation state at once:

```
    GetComponent<Animator>().Play("New Animation",  -1, 0f);
```

Source: https://answers.unity.com/questions/623878/how-to-restart-mecanim-state-animation-or-play-it.html